# MySQL Database row in a Button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a database for my ToDo App which has following cloumns:

```
| ID | ShortDescription | Description | Date | Status |
```

I already can add a Task to the Datatable and can see it in *phphmyadmin*.

I have following code till now:

```php
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$out = 'SELECT * FROM ToDo1 WHERE `id` = '.$id.' LIMIT 1';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $out);

$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<div id= "OutShortDescription">
<?php
echo $row['ShortDescription'];
?>
</div>
<div id= "OutDescription">
<?php
echo $row['Description'];
?>
</div>
<div id= "OutDate">
<?php
echo $row['Date'];
?>
</div>
<div id= "OutStatus">
<?php
echo $row['Status'];
?>
</div>
```

Now I want to put every ID row on a own Site. 
For that I want to make a table of Buttons (*Buttonnumber=ID*).
On this Button should only be shown the `ShortDescription` and when I click it I want to go to a the Site which matches to the Button.

Can someone help me?

EDIT

okay thanks now I have this code but it wont work:

```
    <?php
       $dbname= 'Groups';
       $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname;
       $user = 'root';
       $pass = '';
       $db  = new PDO($dsn, $user,$pass);
       $query = "SELECT * FROM groups2 WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
       $ps = $db->prepare($query);
       $ps->bindParam(':id', $id);
       $ps->execute();
       $row = $ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


       ?>
  <div class="searchwindow">
  <?php
  $data = $link->query('SELECT * FROM Groups2');

foreach($data as $row) { 

 echo '<p><input type="button" onclick="window.location = All_Groups.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . ' value='.$row['ShortDescription'].'  /></p>';
    }
```

I have now following code

```
<div data-role="page" id="SearchPage" data-title="SearchPage">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Search</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">



    <div data-role="header">    

<form>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" align="center" id="selectMenu">


    <select name="selectStatus" id="selectStatus">
        <option value="0">Status</option>
        <option value="1">Done</option>
        <option value="2">In Progress</option>
    </select>


</fieldset>
</form>

</div>
       <?php
       $dbname= 'Groups';
       $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname;
       $user = 'root';
       $pass = '';
       $db  = new PDO($dsn, $user,$pass);
       $query = "SELECT * FROM groups2 WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
       $ps = $db->prepare($query);
       $ps->bindParam(':id', $id);
       $ps->execute();
       $row = $ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


       ?>
  <div class="searchwindow">
  <?php
  $data = $link->query('SELECT * FROM Groups2');

foreach($data as $row) { 

 $path = $row['ID'];
 $description = $row['ShortDescription'];
 echo ("<form action='All_Groups.php?id=$path'><button  type='submit' value='$description'/>$description</form>" );
}
  ?>



  </div>    
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#SearchPage" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="top">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#NewPage" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="top">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#MorePage" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="top">More</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- Ende navbar -->
  </div><!-- Ende footer -->
  </div>
```

And this is my All_groups.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$servername ="localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "Groups";

    $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$link) {
    die('Verbindung nicht möglich : ' . mysqli_error($link) );
}
    ?>

<?php

$row="";
$Date="";
$Status="";
$ShortDescription="";
$Description="";

  mysqli_select_db($link, "groups"); 

?>
</div>
<?php
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$out = "SELECT * FROM groups2 WHERE ID = '$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $out);

$id = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<div id= "OutShortDescription">
<?php
echo $id['ShortDescription'];
?>
</div>
<div id= "OutDescription">
<?php
echo $id['Description'];
?>
</div>
<div id= "OutStatus">
<?php
echo $id['Status'];
?>
</div>
<div id= "OutDate">
<?php
echo $id['Date'];
?>


<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#SearchPage" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="top">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#NewPage" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="top">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#MorePage" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="top">More</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- Ende navbar -->

</div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **"I have following code till now:"**  which code I can't see any code here, can you try to paste some code so we can see what have you tried?

Comment: DON'T USE mysql_* methods!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!! and again don't USE IT!!! `mysql_real_escape_string` is bad. replace it with `mysqli_real_escape_string` ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the mysql_* methods! Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.construct.php) or [mysqli_*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Below, I'm pasting your example query, using PDO:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname;//$dbName is the name of your database
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123';//use your login information here
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user,$pass);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ToDo1 WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
$ps = $db->prepare($query);
$ps->bindParam(':id', $id)
$ps->execute();
$row = $ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now, to get your button, you don't need to use jquery:

```
<?php
    $path = $row['ID'];
    $description = $row['ShortDescription'];
    echo "<form action='your/site/$path'><button type='submit' value='$description'/>$description</form>"
?>
```

Another option is use the `onclick`:

```
<?php
    $path = $row['ID'];
    $description = $row['ShortDescription'];
    echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href='your/site/$path'\" value=\"$description\" />";
?>
```

The `\` before `"` is a escape, so PHP will print the character `"` and not interpret it as the end of your string.

**Advice**: Try to avoid mix HTML and PHP, in general this is a bad practice.

Comment: Do you have any error message in the console? What's the result?

Comment: no error in the console, there is only one empty button and the footer Change the position

Comment: @Moritz. My mistake lay precisely in mixing PHP and HTML. The new code should work correctly.

Comment: okay thank you but when i click on the Buttons nothing happens :/ can you help me maybe?

Comment: @Moritz, do you have any error message in the console when you click? Edit your questinon and include your new code (and also the All_Groups.php). It'll give us some tip of why its not working.

Comment: there is no error message it gets a click Animation but nothing happens thank you james

Comment: Since your buttons are showing well, I think that your problem is now in `All_Groups.php`. Try to change this script to also use PDO instead mysqli_*. Also check your query in some mysql client to ensure that your query is right.

Comment: thank you I have now another Version of the code and it is okay :) but every time I nestart the app there is one mysql row which is completly empty

Comment: @Moritz Then it seems that your problem is no longer in PHP but in SQL, so I suggest you close this question and try to understand where your error is in SQL, perhaps opening another question here in the SO.